# timeline chart not drawing "null" data

Tags: google-sheets

when I use the data below in a google sheets timeline chart it doesn't plot `29/04/2019 5% and 10%` leaving a gap in a chart, how can I resolve this? the chart should be unaffected by empty fields.

```
Date    5% Target   10% Target  Actual
22/04/2019  120.6   120.6   120.6
29/04/2019                  119.5
22/07/2019  114.57  108.54  
22/10/2019  108.84  97.69   
22/01/2020  103.40  87.92   
22/04/2020  98.23   79.13   
22/07/2020  93.32   71.21   
22/10/2020  88.65   64.09   
22/01/2021  84.22   57.68   
22/04/2021  80.01   51.91   
22/07/2021  76.01   46.72   
22/10/2021  72.21   42.05   
22/01/2022  68.60   37.85   
22/04/2022  65.17   34.06   
22/07/2022  61.91   30.65   
22/10/2022  58.81   27.59   
22/01/2023  55.87   24.83   
22/04/2023  53.08   22.35   
22/07/2023  50.43   20.11
```

I have tried adding another dataset and I get the error

> each values column may be followed by one or two annotation columns. column number 4 is of type date

[Here is a link to the spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MOb1njK58ewVh1aukkhDCKrGYolgHd6lNmiS92KlNYM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I have edited it to include a link to the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

There are gaps in your data, so you're going to have gaps in your chart. That's just how Timeline Chart works. There are ways of having charts skip gaps, but you have the 29th as a date, so it is explicitly part of your timeline.

The least burdensome remedy is usually to chart a different dataset living elsewhere, filtered down live from your input values, but meeting your charting requirements. E.g. elsewhere in your file have it list only the rows where 5% Target is populated with something like `=FILTER(B2:E,LEN(C2:C))` and then chart that.

If that's not what you really want, then you need to decide what you really want. A time-cropped chart to only include fully-populated date ranges? A chart with made-up values extrapolated from surrounding data? Those and some other options are not trivial, so you'll need to really determine your requirements and look into how they can be achieved.

Comment: Filtering out row 4 will not give me the actual in E4, which i want to trend. Extrapolated values would work, i'm no spreadsheet wizard so it is definitely something I would have to look into the most comfortable solution, for me, would be to use flot and make a page, however, I was hoping for an easier way.  Thank you, I will take your answer under advisement.